# Select all rows from a table except where row in another table with same id has a particular value in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a query that select all rows from a table except where rows in another table with same id as logged in user and has same value in another column.

```
Table1
id    |    value
=================
1      |    10
2      |    20
3      |    30
4      |    40
5      |    50
6      |    60
```

-

```
Table2
id     |    user_ids   |  another_column
=========================================
1      |       2       |       30
2      |       4       |       50
3      |       4       |       60
```

So if Table2.user_ids = (loggedin userid) and at the same time Table1.value = Table2.another_column - those rows should not be ouputted in the results.

If we say that we have a user with id:4, the user should not see row5 or row6 from Table1 because values matches

Should I go with some kind of subquery or join in the sql?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the user with id 4 from your example above:

```
select * from Table1
where value not in (
  select another_column
  from Table2
  where user_ids = 4
);
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id, value from t1 where value not in (select another_column from t 2 where userid = 4)
```

something like that